Supress screen sharing selection window by always selecting Entire screen with audio in edgewebview2
chrome when i run it with --auto-select-desktop-capture-source="Entire Screen" does audio share as well but edgewebview2 doesn't why?, In chrome I can turn it off by --screen-capture-audio-default-unchecked.
is this flag always enabled in edgewebview2 , i have a webapp which does screensharing running in webview. I tried to do the same for the microsoft edge browser it doesn't work.  Any help is appreciated.   ;)
